# Prove that every interval of real numbers is either open, closed, half open, infinite closed, or infinite open using the completeness property of ℝ.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that every interval of real numbers is either open, closed, half open, infinite closed, or infinite open using the completeness property of ℝ.

open interval:(a,b) = {x ∈ R | a < x < b}
closed interval:[a,b] = {x ∈ R | a ≤ x ≤ b}
half open intervals:(a,b] = {x ∈ R | a < x ≤ b}, [a,b) = {x ∈ R | a ≤ x < b}
infinite open intervals:(a,∞) = {x ∈ R | a > x}, (-∞,b) = {x ∈ R | b < x}
infinite closed intervals:[a,∞) = {x ∈ R | a ≥ x}, (-∞,b] = {x ∈ R | b ≤ x}

I know that I have to split the proof into various cases such as the interval being bounded or unbounded with subcases such as bounded above and/or below and use the completeness property of ℝ.

The completeness property of ℝ was defined as every nonempty subset of ℝ that is bounded above in ℝ has a least upper bound in ℝ.

The definition of interval is S⊆ℝ is an interval if for all a,b ∈ S, a < c < b, then c ∈ S.

Comment: You should edit the question in such a way that it can be understood by an user who did not read its title.

Comment: How are you defining half open, infinite closed, infinite open

Comment: edited with your suggestions, thank you

Comment: By vacuous implication, a singleton would gualify as an interval, accordung to your definition.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention intervals like $(-\infty,b), (-\infty,b]$

The ends of your interval will be $\inf S$ and $\sup S$. It suffices to show that $(\inf S, \sup S) \subseteq S$, which you can prove using properties of $\inf,\sup$ and your property for a set to be an interval. All the intervals you mentioned each contain the interval $(\inf S,\sup S)$, and the only other points can only be the endpoints $\inf S,\sup S$

Comment: thank you, I edited to include those